# Сортировка словаря Python по значениям

Tags: python, сортировка, словари

Дано такой словарь:

```
{
  "ff8bca1c-9640-49dd-9eed-4c9e045bb447": {
    "messages": 7
  },
  "abb3e859-2df7-4dea-8640-d3a19ccf14d5": {
    "messages": 30
  },
  "4598eca1-e2c3-4b29-aea7-275c98d7949d": {
    "messages": 12
  },
  "f3a44385-c700-4c96-bb46-e1da9d53a64c": {
    "messages": 29
  },
  "c698579a-869b-4f2b-93f3-c3dadac020a4": {
    "messages": 2
  },
  "3e7bc03d-a2f6-4851-8c4c-a500d3aab1a2": {
    "messages": 53
  },
  "7c25d5d0-e4a1-4589-8b89-00c7c54d7546": {
    "messages": 9
  },
  "6f63e4ee-f46f-4cf2-b74c-847d1baef684": {
    "messages": 9
  }
}
```

Он записан в отдельном файле "users_data.json"

На всякий случай покажу как этот словарь изменяется и как эти значения туда попадают:

```
def add(uid):
    data_file_path = os.getcwd() + '/users_data.json'

    if not os.path.exists(data_file_path):
        with open(data_file_path, 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as data_file:
            data_file.write(json.dumps({}))
            data_file.close()

    with open(data_file_path, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as data_file:
        users_data = json.loads(data_file.read())
        data_file.close()

    if uid not in users_data:
        users_data[uid] = {'messages': 1}
    else:
        users_data[uid]['messages'] += 1

    with open(data_file_path, 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as data_file:
        data_file.write(json.dumps(users_data, indent=2))
        data_file.close()

    return users_data[uid]['messages']
```

```
    if message:
       warning.add(authorid)
```

Нужно отсортировать этот словарь в зависимости от числа в 'messages'

Пробовал:

```
users_data_p = Path("users_data.json")
users_data = json.loads(users_data_p.read_text(encoding='utf-8'))

users_data = list(users_data.items())
users_data.sort()
  for key, items in users_data:
      print(key, "->", items)
```

Вывод:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Цифры немного изменились в ходе тестирования, но суть в том что словарь не отсортирован как надо)

Comment: Обычный словарь нельзя отсортировать т.к. он не поддерживает порядок. Если нужен порядок — используйте `OrderedDict` из collection.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica с Python 3.7 поддерживает.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Да? Ого, поднялся на python 3.8, и не знал...

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica был так же шокирован. Как по мне, так это ненужный функционал ещё больше снижающий и без того низкое быстродействие.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica можно пример, как это можно реализовать в моем случае, пожалуйста?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, словари теперь не просто сохраняют порядок - они ещё и [быстрее работают](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-December/123028.html) при итерации по ключам и значениям, при добавлении  новых значений (при каждой операции `resize`), занимают в ~2 раза меньше памяти и т.д. Если интересно, то советую посмотреть [видео об эволюции словарей в Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p33CVV29OG8#t=5m16s) от Raymond Hettinger

Comment: @MaxU да смотрел я их внутреннее устройство. Но чудес не бывает, можно было ещё ускорить, но без сохранения порядка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import json

from pathlib import Path

users_data_p = Path("users_data.json")

users_data = json.loads(users_data_p.read_text(encoding='utf-8'))

users_data_list = list(users_data.items())

users_data_list.sort(key=lambda j: j[1].get('messages'))

for i in users_data_list:
    print(i[0], '->', i[1])
```

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо. А для сортировки по убыванию нужно сменить ``for i in users_data_list: print(i[0], '->', i[1])`` на ``for i in users_data_list: print(i[1], '->', i[0])`` ?

Comment: for i in reversed(users_data_list):
    print(i[0], '->', i[1])

Comment: а как можно убрать фигурные скобки и кавычки при выводе значения?
`{'messages': 145}`

Comment: for i in reversed(users_data_list): 
    for key in i[1]:
        print(i[0], '->', key, ':', i[1].get(key))

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(data_file_path) as data_file:
    users_data = json.load(data_file)
    sorted_data = sorted(user_data.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]['messages'])
```

Comment: `sorted_data = sorted(users_data.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]['messages'])`

`TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Вот такую ошибку выдает

Comment: @lynx1 значит в users_data содержаться данные иной структуры, чем приведено у вас в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = {"hi": {"messages": 7}, "lo": {"messages": 4}}
>>> a.items()
dict_items([('hi', {'messages': 7}), ('lo', {'messages': 4})])
>>> sorted(a.items(), key=lambda itm: itm[1]['messages'])
[('lo', {'messages': 4}), ('hi', {'messages': 7})]
```